# Forecast a song ranking for tomorrow

Tags: time-series, forecasting, ordinal-data

I need to forecast the position of a song on a music chart.

EXAMPLE:

- chart from #100 to #1
- my song started from #100 and raised during the days
- my song today is #10 and i know the movements and the sells during the past days
- the more you rise, the most sells you need for top positions (see [this graph](https://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=700%2Fx&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=1&x_max=100&y_min=1&y_max=100&x_tick=10&y_tick=10&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525) for a good approximation)

So, e.g., I might know that yesterday my song sold 30 copies and today 30 (+1), how many tomorrow?

Approximation is accepted and I have an historical database to make some tests:

1. What is my prediction for tomorrow?
2. How many downloads I need to raise n positions?
3. How many downloads were made for a song in position n (can be assumed from 2)?

Answer (score 1):

Predicting the exact rating may be hard, but you can try a simpler model first and see how far you can get with it.

For example, you may try to predict if a song will increase its rating tomorrow or not - and this is a binary classification problem. Features can be any data you can extract from these songs, and you'll probably need to add features of the song one position above and some derived features, e.g. difference in downloads between the songs or what's the difference between downloads of the song today and yesterday.

Another idea (less simple, though) might be building separate Time Series models (e.g. ARIMA) for each of the songs separately, and then get the rating by ordering the songs according to predicted values from the models.